# How to: Add custom Web Part Page in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, webpartpage

I would like to have a custom web part page in SharePoint 2007. I have an application that uses javascript to popup a new window with a web part page. Currently this web part page inherits the look and feel of the site (the default.master). I would like a web part page that i stripped down so that it is almost empty (I guess I still need the ability to add web parts etc.).

Is there a way to do this?

Best regards
Pål Eilertsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was easy to do. I only needed to create a new masterpage and use that one instead. Then I could save the SharePoint site as a template and in code create all the sites I needed, and the new masterpage would follow.